# How do I write SQL query that returns a Date of Birth from DOB column based on the current 'month and day' only?

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime

Seems like a simple litte query.  I'm trying to populate a report viewer on a website that shows "Today's Birthdays".  I just don't know how to write the where statement to filter just for current month and day only to the month and day in the datetime column of my database.

```
SELECT     [Name], [DOB] 
FROM       UserLogon
where      [DOB] =  ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where month(dob) = month(current_timestamp) and day(dob) = day(current_timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
where DATEPART(DAY,DOB)=DATEPART(DAY,getdate()) 
  and DATEPART(MONTH,DOB)=DATEPART(MONTH,getdate())
```